# Query and display train and station information

Tags: python, python-3.x, interview-questions, api

Recently got this coding assignment as the first round of interview at a tech organization. I could get the expected result, however, my code failed the best practices check.

Please let me know if it needs a different approach or specific things are missing. I was confused about how to add tests since this will fetch real-time information which will change.

This was the problem statement (not verbatim, from what I recall):

> There is an API https://api.bart.gov/docs/etd/ for train and
>   station information.

Information provided: API key (or there was an option to generate API key and use that), sample output.

Query and display:

> 1. The current time
> 2. Trains leaving Montogomery Station at the current time
> 3. Restrict up to 10 trains
> 4. Sort result in ascending order of departure time and also mention the destination name.

This was my code:

```
import requests
import json
import sys


class TrainInfo(object):
    def __init__(self, station_code, station_name, number_of_records=10, api_key=API_KEY_PROVIDED):
        self.url =  'http://api.bart.gov/api/etd.aspx?'
        self.station_code = station_code
        self.station_name = station_name
        self.number_of_records = number_of_records
        self.api_key = api_key

    def __get_data(self):
        # private method to make http request and return JSON response
        request_parameters = {'cmd': 'etd',
                              'orig': self.station_code,
                              'key': self.api_key,
                              'json': 'y'}
        try:
            response_object = requests.get(self.url, request_parameters)
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e: 
            print('HTTP get request failed!')
            sys.exit(1)
        try:
            data_to_parse = response_object.json()
        except  json.decoder.JSONDecodeError as e:
            print('HTTP response cannot be converted to JSON!')
            sys.exit(1)
        return data_to_parse

    def __parse_data(self, data):
        # private method to parse the JSON response and return a dictionary where
        # delay times are mapped to destination names
        raw_data = self.__get_data()
        delay_station_map = {}
        # list of dictionaries with destination as key and list of departures to destination(estimate)
        station_data = data['root']['station'][0]['etd']
        for item in station_data:
            for d in item['estimate']:
                # populate dictionary where key =  delay in mins, value = destination
                try:
                    delay_station_map[int(d['minutes'])] = item['destination']
                except ValueError:
                    pass
        return delay_station_map

    def __fetch_data(self):
        raw_data = self.__get_data()
        parsed_data = self.__parse_data(raw_data)
        return parsed_data

    def __print_header(self, current_time):
        # Private method to format and print header line for output
        header_line = "Trains leaving from {} at {}".format(self.station_name, current_time)
        print("*" * len(header_line))
        print(header_line)
        print("*" * len(header_line))

    def get_current_time(self):
        # get the current time from the JSON response
        raw_data = self.__get_data()
        return raw_data['root']['time']

    def print_data(self, curr_time):
        # print header
        self.__print_header(curr_time)
        # get dictionary with delays mapped to destinations
        parsed_data = self.__fetch_data()
        # get destination with max length for formatting output
        length_of_dest_names = [len(value) for value in parsed_data.values()]
        max_dest_length = max(length_of_dest_names)

        for k in sorted(parsed_data.keys())[:self.number_of_records]:
            print(" To {0:{1}} in {2} mins".format(parsed_data[k], max_dest_length, k))


# Test Code
if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_valid_stationid = TrainInfo('MONT', 'Montgomery St.')
    curr_time = test_valid_stationid.get_current_time()
    test_valid_stationid.print_data(curr_time)

#test_invalid_stationid = TrainInfo('INVALID', 'Montgomery St.')
#curr_time = test_invalid_stationid.get_current_time()
#test_invalid_stationid.print_data(curr_time)

#test_input_api_key = TrainInfo('INVALID', 'Montgomery St.')
#curr_time = test_invalid_stationid.get_current_time()
#test_invalid_stationid.print_data(curr_time)

#test_invalid_api_key = TrainInfo('MONT', 'Montgomery St.', api_key='')
#curr_time = test_invalid_api_key.get_current_time()
#test_invalid_api_key.print_data(curr_time)

#test_invalid_api_key = TrainInfo('MONT', 'Montgomery St.', api_key='')
#curr_time = test_invalid_api_key.get_current_time()
#test_invalid_api_key.print_data(curr_time)

#test_change_num_of_records = TrainInfo('MONT', 'Montgomery St.', 5)
#curr_time = test_change_num_of_records.get_current_time()
#test_change_num_of_records.print_data(curr_time)
```

Comment: I rephrased your question to be more in line with what is suggested at the [guide on how to write a good question](/help/how-to-ask). Feel free to change it again if I misunderstood something.

Comment: 1) For which Python version is this written? 2) Are you aware you've posted an API key in public view?

Comment: @Mast: 1) Python 3.4                                                                                                   2) The key was provided in the question, I have now edited my question to remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the class, I would use just methods, and string those together:

- query the information for a station
- parsing this info to get the departure information
- sort that info in the requested order
- display this information

## `sys.exit`

Why do you exit the program if an error occurs? Now no one else can use this method. Better would be to raise an appropriate exception, and let the caller handle this. Fail fast, fail hard, but also fail clearly, so you can find out what exactly happened.

## getting the response

This can be as simple as

BART_URL = "http://api.bart.gov/api/edt.aspx"

```
def get_edt(
    station_code: str, *, api_key: str = API_KEY_PROVIDED, url: str = BART_URL,
):
    """queries api.bart.gov for the departure data of the station"""
    request_parameters = {
        "cmd": "edt",
        "key": api_key,
        "json": "y",
        "orig": station_code,
    }
    response = requests.get(url, request_parameters)
    return response.json()
```

This will raise a `ConnectionError` when no connection can be established, or a `JSONDecodeError` if the response is not parsable. You can extend this method in a few ways

```
class FetchException(Exception): pass

def get_edt(
    station_code: str, *, api_key: str = API_KEY_PROVIDED, url: str = BART_URL,
):
    """queries api.bart.gov for the departure data of the station"""
    request_parameters = {
        "cmd": "edt",
        "key": api_key,
        "json": "y",
        "orig": station_code,
    }
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, request_parameters)
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        raise FetchException(f"no connection to {url} could be established")
    if response.status_code != "200":
        raise FetchException(f"""
        something went wrong when fetching the data. status_code: {response.status_code}
        {response.text}
        """)
    return response.json()
```

## parsing the response

Getting the time and station name out of the response is fairly easy:

```
def parse_header(response):
    root = response["root"]
    time = root["time"]
    station = root["station"][0]
    station_name = station["name"]

    return {
        "time": time,
        "station": station_name
    }
```

You can simplify this by returning a `tuple` or extend the capabilities by transforming the date and time to a `datetime`, returning a `namedtuple` or even a `Header` object, depending on how far you want to go here. I think the `dict` is a nice balance between simplicity and extensibility.

For the example response on the Bart website this returns `{'time': '10:20:31 AM PDT', 'station': 'Richmond'}`

## parse the departures

What is important about these departures is the destination and minutes until departure. Since the response is a nested structures, grouped per destination, the simplest would be to use a double loop, and just yield the departures

```
def parse_departures(response):
    try:
        departures = response["root"]["station"][0]["etd"]
    except (KeyError, IndexError):
        raise ValueError("invalid response")
    for destination_info in departures:
        destination = destination_info["destination"]
        for estimates in destination_info.get("estimate", []):
            minutes_str = estimates["minutes"]
            if minutes_str == "leaving":
                minutes = 0
            else:
                minutes = int(minutes_str) + int(estimates.get("delay", 0))
            yield minutes, destination
```

> ```
> list(parse_departures(response))
> ```

```
[(239, 'Fremont'),
 (13, 'Fremont'),
 (28, 'Fremont'),
 (6, 'Millbrae'),
 (21, 'Millbrae'),
 (36, 'Millbrae')]
```

Since this is a tuple with the minutes until departure as first element, sorting requires just a call to `sorted`

### bug

There is also a possible bug in your __parse_data method. In `delay_station_map`, if there is a train leaving the the same time but on another platform, `delay_station_map[int(d['minutes'])] = item['destination']` will overwrite one of those.

## putting it together

This can go behind a `__main__` guard

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
#     response = get_edt("MONT",)
    header = parse_header(response)
    departures = sorted(parse_departures(response))

    print(f"trains departing from {header['station']} at {header['time']}")
    print("=-" * 10)
    for minutes, destination in departures[:10]:
        print(f"in {minutes} minutes the train to {destination} leaves")
```

again, with the example response:

> ```
> trains departing from Richmond at 10:20:31 AM PDT
> =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
> in 6 minutes the train to Millbrae leaves
> in 13 minutes the train to Fremont leaves
> in 21 minutes the train to Millbrae leaves
> in 28 minutes the train to Fremont leaves
> in 36 minutes the train to Millbrae leaves
> in 239 minutes the train to Fremont leaves
> ```

## overall

Since there is very little state, there is little reason to use a class. Especially a convoluted one as yours. Try to think of the different steps needed to get to the solution, and try to split your code according to those steps. That will generally be the clearest code, which needs the least explanation and comments, and is most easily testable. The units have the least effect on each other.

Brandon Rhodes has a nice talk on clean architecture [here](https://rhodesmill.org/brandon/talks/#clean-architecture-python)

And Jack Diederich has a very well known talk about when not to use classes [here](https://youtu.be/o9pEzgHorH0). This is one of the cases where a class is overkill. If you later want to display more information, like the platform, direction, color etc, you can think about introducing classes to this problem, if a dict doesn't suffice anymore.

In your solution, the data is fetched 3 times, once for the current time, twice to get the departures. This should be a giveaway that something is wrong.

Trying to figure out what went on in the code took some jumping back and forth as well, while using the smaller methods, strung together almost explains itself.

Comment: Thank you, this looks very clean! My initial solution did not have any class because I did not find it would be useful either. But I was specifically asked to submit again by implementing OOP

Answer (score 0):

In general if you have try blocks like yours

```
    try:
        response_object = requests.get(self.url, request_parameters)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e: 
        print('HTTP get request failed!')
        sys.exit(1)
    try:
        data_to_parse = response_object.json()
    except  json.decoder.JSONDecodeError as e:
        print('HTTP response cannot be converted to JSON!')
        sys.exit(1)
    return data_to_parse
```

You should rewrite them to

```
    try:
        response_object = requests.get(self.url, request_parameters)
        data_to_parse = response_object.json()
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e: 
        print('HTTP get request failed!')   
        sys.exit(1)
    except  json.decoder.JSONDecodeError as e:
        print('HTTP response cannot be converted to JSON!')
        sys.exit(1)

    return data_to_parse
```

I think is a bit more cleaner this way, but you choose :)

Comment: The code in the finally block will execute even if there is no exception and we do not want the code to stop execution if there's no exception

Comment: Yes you are right, just correct now thanks

Comment: I try to limit my try-catch blocks as much as possible, so it is as clear as possible what part can raise which exception. I don't think moving from 2 blocks to 1 is an improvement